# Sympy relational symbol in set

Tags: python, sympy, discrete-mathematics, integer-programming

I have a FiniteSet and a symbol with which I want to associate a Relation such that the symbol is in the FiniteSet, is it possible with sympy? `symbol in FiniteSet` does not return an expression, but instead evaluates it:

```
>>> from sympy import *   
>>> s = FiniteSet(range(0,3))
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> x in s
False
>>> Eq(x,s)
x == {0, 1, 2}
>>> In(x,s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'In' is not defined
```

Edit: Thanks to ohe for telling me about `Contains`. I updated my version of sympy, by the way the syntax of FinitSet also changed in the update. I give the small example that I expected to work in the first place for the record:

```
>>> from sympy import *   
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> s = FiniteSet(*range(0,3))
>>> init_printing()
>>> Contains(x,s)
x ∈ {0, 1, 2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for might be the `Contains` function.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation? It's not really easy to find the `contains` function :)

Comment: @Emilien what you want is indeed `Contains`, but you need at least SymPy 0.7.6 for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work for me.
The expression

```
x in s
```

raises an exception.
You have to assign a value to x first.
Then you can just use "in".

Like this:

```
s = FiniteSet(range(0,3))
x = symbols('x')
x=3
x in s # False
```

Here is the complete setup:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> s=FiniteSet(range(0,3))
>>> x=symbols("x")
>>> x in s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\lhk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\sets\sets.py", line 497, in __contains__
    raise TypeError('contains did not evaluate to a bool: %r' % symb)
TypeError: contains did not evaluate to a bool: Contains(x, {range(0, 3)})
>>> x=3
>>> x in s
False
>>> Contains(x,s)
False
>>>
```

Comment: It's weird, but I only use it to illustrate what I do not want anyway. For the record I use sympy version 0.7.5.

Comment: Sorry I just figured out that the result for `x in s` was not in my question, it answers False with my version of sympy (but still that's not what I'm looking for)